# Why cannot be converted to an expression tree?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I try to build a anonymous function for the linq function Any. I don't understand why cannot do it:

```
found = db.Label.Any(lb => {
    var shortNames = lb.lbShortName.Split('/').ToList();

    bool foundShortName = false;
    foreach (var shortName in shortNames)
    {
        if (String.Compare(shortName, name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            foundShortName = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return foundShortName;
```

Or better, what I don't understand is why is an `Expression(Func(,))` and not a `Func(,)`
                    });

Comment: thats a quite complex function! linq really does well for simple things. perhaps you could break this into separate steps with projections.

Comment: EF needs expressions so it can convert the Linq code into SQL.

Comment: Also, if i read your code right, you could just do a single `Contains` call.

Comment: @DanielA.White Except for the `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` part...

Comment: @DStanley an alternate would be an index of.

Comment: @DStanley that would depend on the collation of the SQL server. The default behavior is to ignore case, but that is only the default.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Good point - I was thinking more of the Linq-to-Objects behavior than SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using a Linq provider like LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework. It's trying to convert the expression to something like a SQL query, and it's not simple enough for this. This would work OK if `db.Label` was a plain `IEnumerable<>` instead of an `IQueryable<>`.

Comment: Can I use a function instead of an expression when the set is IQueryable?

Comment: No. The query engine inspects the _code expression_ (you're not actually passing a `Func<Label, bool>`, but an `Expression<Func<Label, bool>>`), and it won't know what the function actually does. You're stuck with using an expression that can be translated to SQL, or if you want .NET to run the code, run the query first (`.ToList()`) and then perform the changes, though that doesn't work for your needs in this case.